# Error when trying to get Cases from input

Tags: apex, class

Trying to get a list of cases that are equal to the cases in the variable caseInputs but i get three errors.

1.Invalid bind expression type of Integer for column of type String->its probably regarding my sql query?
2. Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void containsKey(Integer) from the type Map<String,String>
3. Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void get(Integer) from the type Map<String,String>

Never worked with maps but i guess its because ive an integer variable but iam mapping an integer and string variable?

```
public with sharing class Cases {

  public class CaseOutput {
    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
    public String sCaseStatus;
  }

  public class CaseInput {
    @InvocableVariable(required=true)
    public Integer sCaseNumber;
  }

  @InvocableMethod(label='Get Case Status')
  public static List<CaseOutput> getCaseStatus(List<CaseInput> caseInputs) {
    Set<Integer> caseNumbers = new Set<Integer>(); 

    // Get the case numbers from the input
    for (CaseInput caseInput : caseInputs) {
      caseNumbers.add(caseInput.sCaseNumber);
    }

    // Get the case objects from the set of order numbers
    List<Case> cases = 
      [SELECT casenumber,subject, status FROM Case WHERE casenumber in :caseNumbers];
      
    // Create a map of case numbers and case status values
    Map<String, String> mapNameStatus = new Map<String, String>(); 
    if (cases.size() > 0) {
        for (Case oneCase : cases) {
          mapNameStatus.put(oneCase.Subject, oneCase.Status);
        }
    }
    
    // Build a list of case status values for the output
    List<CaseOutput> caseOutputs = new List<CaseOutput>();
    for (CaseInput caseInput : caseInputs) {
      CaseOutput caseOutput = new CaseOutput();
      
      // Do we have a status for this case number?
      if (mapNameStatus.containsKey(caseInput.sCaseNumber)) {
          // If so, then add the status
          caseOutput.sCaseStatus = mapNameStatus.get(caseInput.sCaseNumber);
      } else {
          // If not, then add an unknown status value
          caseOutput.sCaseStatus = 'Case not found';
      }
      caseOutputs.add(caseOutput);
    }

    return caseOutputs;    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are checking String inside the set of Integers. Replace all the "Integer" with "String" and it should resolve those errors.

Comment: Isnt CaseNumber a Number in salesforce? Should i cast it to text in the code above?

Comment: Thats so weird yesterday it didnt found cases but today its working thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment and code don't agree here:

```
// Create a map of case numbers and case status values
Map<String, String> mapNameStatus = new Map<String, String>(); 
if (cases.size() > 0) {
    for (Case oneCase : cases) {
      mapNameStatus.put(oneCase.Subject, oneCase.Status);
    }
}
```

I think you want (changing the map key type as well

```
// Create a map of case numbers and case status values
Map<Integer, String> mapNameStatus = new Map<Integer, String>(); 
if (cases.size() > 0) {
    for (Case oneCase : cases) {
      mapNameStatus.put(oneCase.CaseNumber, oneCase.Status);
    }
}
```

This can be rewritten to be clearer (if list is empty, loop will do nothing)

```
// Create a map of case numbers and case status values
Map<Integer, String> statusByCaseNumber = new Map<Integer, String>(); 
for (Case case : cases) {
      statusByCaseNumber.put(case.CaseNumber, case.Status);
    }
}
```

Maps should be named *foosByBar* where *foos* describe the map's value and *Bar* describes the map's key. This notation makes it so much easier to understand what a map contains

In addition, since Apex is a by reference system, a better map (more extensible) would be:

```
// Pivot cases by casenumber
Map<Integer, Case> casesByCaseNumber = new Map<Integer, Case>(); 
for (Case case : cases) {
      casesByCaseNumber.put(case.CaseNumber, case);
    }
}
```